# Why order(e.g. source.cxx -lstatic) is enforced while linking with static library?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, static-libraries, linker-errors

While linking with static library, why the order is enforced ?

> g++ -ldynamic -lstatic src.cxx  //ERROR
>
> g++ -lstatic src.cxx -ldynamic //ERROR
>
> g++ src.cxx -ldynamic **-lstatic** //SUCCESS
>
> g++ -ldynamic src.cxx -lstatic //SUCCESS

Is there a technical reason why static library cannot be linked like dynamic libraries (at any order ) ?

Why linking libraries cannot be made generic (may be by mentioning while compiling/linking e.g. for static : `-ls` and for dynamic : `-ld` etc.) ?

Comment: That's the way the tools work - voting to close on opinion based,.

Comment: Sorry, I am expecting a technical answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The *As Needed* schism in Linux linkage**

Your example:

```
g++ -ldynamic -lstatic src.cxx # ERROR

g++ -ldynamic src.cxx -lstatic # SUCCESS
```

indicates that your linux distro belongs to the RedHat clan. Let's just confirm
that, say on CentOS 7:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) \
(gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) ) \
#1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017


$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

$ cat bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

$ cat main.c
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c foo.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
$ gcc -Wall -c bar.c
$ ar cr libbar.a bar.o
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c
$ gcc -o prog -L. -lfoo -lbar main.o -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# :(
$ gcc -o prog -L. -lfoo main.o -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ # :)
$ ./prog
foo
bar
```

So you're right there.

Now let's check it out on a distro from the Debian clan:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.13.0-32-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-016) \
(gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)) \
#35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018
```

Here, it all goes the same as far as:

```
$ gcc -o prog -L. -lfoo -lbar main.o -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo'
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when it gets different. Now the linkage can't resolve *either* `foo` - from the
shared library `libfoo.so` - or `bar` - from the static library `libbar.a`. And
to fix that we need:

```
$ gcc -o prog -L. main.o -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ ./prog
foo
bar
```

with *all* the libraries mentioned after the object file(s) - `main.o` - that
reference the symbols they define.

The Centos-7 (RedHat) linkage behaviour is old-school. The Ubuntu 17.10 (Debian)
linkage behaviour was introduced in Debian 7, 2013, and trickled down
to the Debian-derived distros. As you see, it abolishes the distinction
between shared libraries and static libraries as regards the library needing,
or not needing, to appear in the linkage sequence *after* all input
files that reference it. They all must appear in dependency order (DO<sup>1</sup>),
shared libraries and static libraries alike.

This comes down to how the distro decides to build their version of the GCC
toolchain - how they choose the default options that get passed to the system
linker (`ld`) behind the scenes when it is invoked by one of the language
front-ends (`gcc`, `g++`, `gfortran` etc.) to execute a linkage for you.

Specifically, it comes down to whether the linker option [`--as-needed`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)
is, or is not, inserted by default into the `ld` commandline before the libraries
are inserted.

If `--as-needed` is not in effect then a shared library `libfoo.so` is arrived at,
then it will be linked regardless of whether the linkage has so far accrued any
unresolved references to symbols that the shared library defines. In short,
it will be linked regardless of any proven *need* to link it. Maybe the further
progess of the linkage, to subsequent inputs, will give rise to unresolved references
that `libfoo.so` resolves, justifying its linkage. But maybe not. It gets linked
anyhow. That's the RedHat way.

If `--as-needed` *is* in effect when a `libfoo.so` is arrived at, then it
will be linked if and only if it exports a definition for at least one symbol
to which an unresolved reference has *already* accrued in the linkage, i.e.
there is a proven need to link it. It cannot end up linked if there is
no need to link it. That's the Debian way.

The RedHat way with shared library linkage was prevalent until Debian 7
broke ranks.  But the linkage of static libraries has *always* conformed to the *as needed* principle
by default. There's no `--as-needed` option that applies to static libraries.
Instead there's the opposite, [`--whole-archive`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html):
you need to use that to override the default behaviour and link object files from static libraries regardless of need.
So folks like you, in RedHat land, observe this puzzling difference: by default static libaries
have to be linked in DO; for shared libraries, any order will do by default.
Folks is Debian land see so such difference.

**Wny so?**

Since the Redhat way has this puzzling difference - a stumbling block for
the linkage efforts of the uninitiated - it's natural to ask *why*, historically,
it was *as needed* for static libraries, but *not as needed* for shared libraries,
as a matter of course, and why it still goes in RedHat land.

Simplifying grossly, the linker assembles a program (or shared library) by
incrementally populating *sections* and *dynamic dependency records* (DDRs<sup>2</sup>) in
a structure of sections and DDRs that starts off empty and
ends up being a binary file that the OS loader can parse and successfully map
into a process address space: e.g. an ELF executable or DSO. (*Section*
here is a genuine technical term. *Dynamic dependency record* isn't.
I've just coined now for convenience.)

Loosely speaking, the linker inputs that drive this process are object files,
shared libraries, or static libraries. But *strictly* speaking, they are *either
object files or shared libraries*. Because a static libary is simply
an [`ar` archive](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) of files that happen to be
object files. As far as the linker is concerned it is just a sequence of object
files that it might or might not need to use, archived together with a symbol table
by which the linker can query which of the object files, if any, defines a symbol.

When the linker arrives at an object file, that object file is *always* linked
into the program. The linker never asks whether it *needs* an object file
(whatever that might mean). Any object file is an unconditional *source* of linkage
needs, that further inputs have to satisfy.

When an object file is input, the linker has to dismantle it into
the *input* sections of which it composed and merge them into the *output*
sections in the program. When an input section *S* appears in one object
file, the chances are that a section *S* will appear in other object files;
maybe all of them. The linker has to stitch together all the input `S` sections
into a single output `S` section in the program, so it isn't finally done
with composing an output section `S` till the linkage is finished.

When a shared library `libfoo.so` is input to the linkage, the linker outputs
a DDR into the program (if it decides that the library is needed, or doesn't care). That is essentialy a memo that will be read at runtime by
the loader, telling it that `libfoo.so` is a dependency of the process that is
under construction; so it will locate `libfoo.so` by its standard search algorithm,
load it and map it into the process.

Consuming an object file is a relatively costly bit of linkage; consuming
a shared library is relatively cheap - especially if the linker does not
have to bother beforehand figuring out whether the shared library is *needed*.
The input/output section processing of an object file is typically more bother than writing out a DDR.
But more important than the effort, linking an object file typically makes the program signficantly
larger, and *can* make it arbitarily larger. Linking a shared library adds
only a DDR, which is always a tiny thing.

So there's a respectable rationale for a linkage strategy to reject the linking of
an object file unless it is needed, but to tolerate the linking of a shared library
without need. Linking an unnecessary object file adds an arbitrary amount of dead
weight to the program, at a proportional burden on the linkage. But
if the linker doesn't have to prove that a shared library is *needed*, then it
can link it in a jiffy adding negligibly to the bulk of the program. And if the developer has chosen to add the shared library to the linkage, chances are good it will be needed. The RedHat
camp still thinks that rationale is good enough.

The Debian camp also has a respectable rationale of course. Yes, a Debian linkage
involves the extra effort of determining whether `libfoo.so`, when it is
reached, defines any symbol to which there is an unresolved reference at that
point. But by only linking shared libraries that are needed: -

- At runtime, the loader is spared the wastage of either loading redundant
  dependencies, or figuring out that they are redundant so as not to load them.
- Package management with respect to runtime dependencies is eased if
  redundant runtime dependencies are weeded out at linktime.
- Developers, like you, do not get tripped up by the inconsistent linkage rules
  for static and shared libraries! - a snag that's aggravated by the fact that
  `-lfoo` in the linker commandline does not reveal whether it will resolve
  to `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a`.

There are thornier pros and cons for each side in the schism.

Now consider how the linker uses a static library, `libabc.a` - a list of object files `a.o, b.o, c.o`.
The *as needed* principle is applied, like this: When the linker arrives at `libabc.a`,
it has 0 or more unresolved symbol references in hand that it has carried
forward from the 0 more object files and shared libraries it has already linked
into the program. The linker's question is: *Are there any object files in
this archive that provide definitions for any of these unresolved symbol references?*
If there are 0 such unresolved references, then the answer is trivially *No*. So
there's no need to look in the archive. `libabc.a` is passed over. The linker moves
on to the next input. If it has got some unresolved symbol references in hand, then the
linker inspects the symbols that are defined by the object files in the archive. It
extracts just those object files - if any - that provide symbol definitions that it needs
<sup>3</sup> and inputs those object files to the linkage, exactly as if they were individually
named in the commandline and `libabc.a` was not mentioned at all. Then it moves
it on to the next input, if any.

It's obvious how the *as needed* principle for static libraries implies DO. No
object file will be extracted from a static library and linked unless an unresolved
reference to some symbol that the object file defines has accrued from some
object file (or shared library) *already* linked.

**Must static libraries be *As Needed* ?**

In RedHat land, where DO is waived for shared libraries, what we do in
its absence is just *link every shared library that is mentioned*. And as we've
seen, this is tolerably cheap in linkage resource and program size. If we
also waived DO for static libraries, the equivalent strategy would
be to *link every object file in every static library that is mentioned*. But
that is exorbitantly costly, in linkage resource and program dead weight.

If we wanted to be free of DO for static libraries, but still *not* link
object files with no need, how could the linker proceed?

Maybe like this?:-

- Link all of the object files that are explicitly mentioned into the program.
- Link all the shared libraries mentioned.
- See if there remain any unresolved references. If so, then -
- Extract all of the object files from all of the static libraries that are mentioned
  into a pool of *optional* object files.
- Then carry on the linkage on an *as needed* basis against this pool of optional
  object files, to success or failure.

But nothing like this will fly. The first definition of a symbol that the linker
sees is the one that's linked. This means that the order in which object files
are linked matters, even as between two different linkage orders that *are both
successful*.

Say that object files `a.o, b.o` have already been linked; unresolved references
remain and then the linker has a choice of optional object files `c.o, d.o, e.o, f.o`
to continue with.

There may be *more than one* ordering of `c.o, d.o, e.o, f.o` that
resolves all references and gives us a program. It might be the case that linking,
say, `e.o` first resolves all outstanding references and yields no new ones,
giving a program; while linking say `c.o` first also resolves all outstanding
references *but* produces some new ones, which require the linking of some or
all of `d.o, e.o, f.o` - depending on the order - with each possible linkage
resulting in yet another different program.

That's not all. There may be more that one ordering of `c.o, d.o, e.o, f.o` such that, after some object file is linked - *point P* - all 
previously outstanding references are resolved, but where:-

1. Some of those orderings either produce no new references at point *P* or produce only references that some further linkage order can resolve.
2. Other ones produce new references at point *P* that no further linkage order can resolve.

So, whenever the linker discovers it has made a type 2 choice at some earlier point, it would need
to backtrack to that point and try one of the other choices that were then available, *that it hasn't already tried*,
and only conclude that the linkage fails when it has tried them all unsuccessfully.
Linking like this against a pool of *N* optional object files will take time proportional
to factorial *N* to fail.

Living with DO for static libraries as we do now, we specify object files and/or static libraries *Ij* in the
linker commandline in some order:

```
I0, I1, ... In
```

and this equates to an ordering of object files which for argument's sake might
ressemble:

```
O0, O1, [02,... O2+j], O2+j+1, [O2+j+2,... O2+j+k] ...
```

where `[Oi...]` is a sub-sequence of *optional* object files (i.e. a static library) that will be
available to the linker at that point.

*Whether we know it not* when we compose the commandline, we are asserting not just that this order is
a good DO ordering that can be linked to yield *some* program, but also that *this*
ordering yields the program that we *intend*.

We might be mistaken on the first count ( = linkage failure). We might even be
mistaken on the second ( = a mean linkage bug). But if we stop caring about the order of these
inputs and just leave it to the linker somehow to find a good DO over them, or prove that there isn't one,
then:

- We have actually stopped caring about *which program* we will get, if any.
- We have stopped caring about whether linkage will terminate in any feasible time.

This is not going to happen.

**Couldn't we get a warning for broken DO?**

In a comment you asked why the linker could not at least *warn* us if our
static object files and static libraries are not in DO.

That would be in addition to failing the linkage, as it does now. But to give us this
additional warning the linker would have to prove that the linkage failed
*because the object files and static libraries are not in DO*, and not just because
there are references in the linkage that nothing in the linkage defines. And it
could only prove that the linkage failed because of broken DO by proving that
*some program* can be linked by some permutation of the object files and static libraries.
That's a factorial-scale task, and we don't care if *some* program can be linked,
if the program we *intend* to link can't be: the linker has no information about
what program we intend to link except the inputs we give it, in the order that
we give them.

It would be easy make the linker (or more plausibly, the GCC frontends) emit a warning if any library was mentioned
before any object file in the commandline. But it would have some nuisance value, because
such a linkage isn't necessarily going to fail and might in fact be the intended
linkage. "Libraries after object files" is just pretty good guidance for routine
invocations of the linker via a GCC frontend. Worse, such a warning would only be practical for *object files after libraries* and not for cases of broken DO *between libraries*, so it would only do some of the job.

---

[1] My abbreviation.

[2] Also my abbreviation.

[3] More precisely, object file extraction from a static library is recursive.
The linker extracts any object files that define unresolved references it
already had in hand, *or* any new unresolved references that accrue while
linking object files extracted from the library.

Answer (score 1):

When the linker loads the library `static`, it will see if any symbols from it are needed. It will use the symbols that are needed, and discard the rest. That of course means that if no symbols are needed from the library then all are discarded.

This is the reason that putting the library in front of the object files that depends on it will not work.

As a rule of thumb, always place libraries (even dynamic) at the end of the command line. And in order of dependencies. If module (object file or library) `A` depend on module `B`, always put `A` before `B`.

Comment: Ok.. understood. But why can't the compiler take the arguments in any order and then process it accordingly based on the argument type ?

Comment: @Sitesh That could mean that the linker would have to keep a lot of data in memory to keep track of it all. And traditionally memory is expensive and rare. The current way also makes linking much simpler and streamlined.

Comment: ok, the responsibility is on the user. But shouldn't the linker at least warn in such cases ?